# Numbers in string to be callable

Tags: android, textview

I am working on my Android app, and I saved some text that containts data, phone numbers and e-mail adresses in my strings.xml file and I display that text in my TextView. Is it possible to make when someone click on phone number to call that number ? I wanna make same with e-mail adresses...

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Answer (score 10):

Use this line in you textView Xml for phone

```
    android:autoLink="phone" 
    android:linksClickable="true"
```

and this for email:

```
   android:autoLink="email" 
   android:linksClickable="true"
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check for email, phone number and url use these lines:

```
    android:autoLink="web|email|phone"
    android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: In my string I have large amount of data that contains mix of simple sentences, phone numbers and e-mail adresses. Your answer is good but only when my string contain only phone number or e-mail adress in second example..

Comment: Ah! i see check out the edit that i made in the answer. Hope it helps!